# How to mix C++ shared pointers and object references

Tags: c++, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, shared-ptr

I have the following code that uses a C++ object of class `Datum` within an Objective-C function `work`:

```
void work(const Datum &datum) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Work with datum.
    });
}
```

This code is called with an instance that is actually a `boost::shared_ptr<Datum>`, i.e.

```
boost::shared_ptr<Datum> the_datum(new Datum());
work(*the_datum);
```

In this situation it is possible that the instance `the_datum` gets deallocated before the block is run inside `work` (the call to `dispatch_async` performs an asynchronous operation on `datum` that is executed later; the call and thus the function `work` return immediately). This obviously results in a disaster.

One solution might be to not pass a reference to `work`, but a `boost::shared_ptr<Datum>`, instead. But there may be situations when references are preferred, see e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855951/sharing-object-by-reference-or-pointer). Is there any way to keep the interface of `work` (i.e., pass `datum` as a reference), but still prevent the deallocation of the shared pointer prior to the completion of the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this by leaving the interface to `work()` the same, and pass in a reference to `datum`. There is no way to use the `datum` to prevent the reference count from decrementing. Consider the following buggy program:

```
#include <memory>
int main () {
    std::shared_ptr<int> p1(new int);
    int &x = *p1;
    std::shared_ptr<int> p2(&x);
}
```

This code crashes with a double free, because the `shared_ptr<>` control structure does not follow the pointer to the object, but is followed through `shared_ptr<>` itself.

What you can do is change `work()` to take a `shared_ptr()`, but add some more code to the block passed to `dispatch_async()` so that it can use a reference within that code. Since you are transferring ownership to the asynchronous routine, you should use `unique_ptr<>` instead. I know zilch about Objective-C, so this syntax might be wrong:

```
void work(std::unique_ptr<Datum> &datumptr_ref) {
    __block std::unique_ptr<Datum> datumptr(std::move(datumptr_ref));
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        Datum &datum = *datumptr
        // Work with datum.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage the references yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

extern "C" {
    typedef struct TagShared Shared;
    Shared* allocate(const std::shared_ptr<int>& ptr) {
        return (Shared*) new std::shared_ptr<int>(ptr);
    }
    void deallocate(Shared* shared) {
        delete (std::shared_ptr<int>*)shared;
    }
 } // extern "C"

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> s(new int(1));
    Shared* p = allocate(s);
    // Inside Dispatch
        // No C++ but similar defined for TagShared
        std::cout << **(std::shared_ptr<int>*)p << std::endl;
        deallocate(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use smart pointers at all within the solution you suggest? And why not use an `intrusive_ptr` instead of manual allocation and deallocation? At least this would allow handling the situation that the smart pointer may be in scope elsewhere while the dispatched block is being executed.

Comment: @user8472 sure, with an intrusive pointer you might get rid of allocate/dealllocate, but introduce inc_ref/dec_ref

Answer (score 0):

You want to *transfer ownership* with `std::unique_ptr` something like this:

```
void work(std::unique_ptr<Datum> datum) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Work with datum.
    });
}

std::unique_ptr<Datum> the_datum(new Datum());
work(std::move(the_datum));
```

Comment: Objective-C blocks copy captured C++ objects, so you cannot use `std::unique_ptr` here.

Comment: @Paul The solution you suggest is similar to using a `boost::shared_ptr<Datum>` as I wrote above. My question is if it is possible to keep the interface of work, i.e., use an object reference `Datum&` instead of a smart pointer.